# Showing that any logically valid open wf must be an instance of a tautology.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , forth edition , exercise 2.25.The question is like this:

> Exhibit a logically valid wf that is not an instance of a tautology.
> However, show that any logically valid open wf (that is, a wf without
> quantifiers) must be an instance of a tautology.

For the first part , I think $\lnot (\exists y)(\forall x)(A^2_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x))$ is a right example .But I wasn't able to prove this rigorously.

For the second part , I was only able to prove that:

> Every instance of a tautology is true for any interpretation.

But I am all out of ideas about How to use this lemma to prove the main theorem. Can someone give me a hint about this?

Comment: If we have equality, consider $\forall x (x=x)$ it is valid but it is not an instance of a tautology. Without equality, any instance of the quantifier axiom: $\forall x Px \to P[t/x]$

Comment: For the second part, I think you can use [this Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040634/if-beta-is-an-mathcall-formula-and-beta-p-is-a-tautology-then-beta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample to the first part is correct. $\lnot (\exists y)(\forall x)(A^2_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x))$ cannot be true, because no matter what value we assign to $y$, if we assign the same value to $x$, then $A^2_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x)$ is false. (I leave it to you to translate this into a formal proof using Mendelson's definition of satisfaction. Mendelson (like most writers) restricts tautologies to propositional formulas, which don't allow quantifiers. So the only propositional formulas that could have $\lnot (\exists y)(\forall x)(A^2_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x))$ as an instance have the form $A$ or $\lnot A$, where $A$ is a propositional variable: neither of these forms is a tautology.

For the second part, if a formula with no quantifiers is valid, then it must be valid in every interpretation in a domain with just $1$ element. But then the arguments to the predicate symbols $A_j^n$ are irrelevant and the $A_j^n$ just represent fixed truth values. So the formula can only hold if it holds for every assignment of a fixed truth value to each $A_j^n$, which means it is an instance of a tautology.

Comment: I know that $\lnot (\exists y)(\forall x)(A^2_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x))$ is logically valid . But I don't know how to prove rigorously that $\lnot (\exists y)(\forall x)(A^2_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x))$ is not an instance of a tautology.

Comment: I've added something about this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if the above answer really provides a solution to this exercise.
For example, the statement form $A=>B$ is not a tautology,
but the instance $A_1^1(x)=>A_1^1(y)$ of this statement form is true for any interpretation whose domain consists of only one element.
In Exercise 2.52 of Mendelson book, a hint is given (but I am not able to use it to solve this exercise).

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed as follows.

Assume $\mathscr C$ is logically valid and open. If it is not an instance of a tautology, replace each occurrence of an atomic subformula with some new statement letter, with the same letter when exactly the same subformula appears more than once. This new formula is not a tautology, or we could make a reverse procedure and have $\mathscr C$ to be an instance of a tautology. Find a row in the truth table where it is false.

We construct an interpretation $M$ in the language of $\mathscr C$ as follows. Take as a domain $D$ the set of all terms in $\mathscr C$.

If $f^n_j$ is a functional letter, let us denote by $A$ the set of all tuples $(t_1,\dots,t_n)$, where $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are terms, such that $f^n_j(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ occurs in $\mathscr C$. For each $a=(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in A$ let $(f^n_j)^M(a)=f^n_j(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in D$, and if $a\in D^n-A$, let $(f^n_j)^M(a)=m$ for some fixed $m\in D$ (it does not matter which).

If $a_j$ is a constant, let $(a_j)^M=a_j\in D$.

If $A^n_j$ is a predicate, look for its atomic instances in $\mathscr C$, if its corresponding statement letter is true, add a tuple with its terms in $(A^n_j)^M$.

Now, if $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are variables occurring in $\mathscr C$, let $s$ be a sequence of elements $x_1,\dots,x_n\in D$ that repeats them. This sequence does not satisfy $\mathscr C$, which makes it not true, contradicting logical validity.