# Tautologies are valid: Mistake in proof?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I think there is a mistake in a proof in *A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic* by Leary and Kristiansen.

Section 2.4.3, exercise 6

> Prove that if $\theta$ is not valid, then $\theta_P$ is not a tautology. Deduce that if $\theta_P$ is a tautology, then $\theta$ is valid.

*(Note that if $\theta$ is a first-order formula, then $\theta_P$ refers to the propositional formula one obtains by first replacing all subformulas of $\theta$ beginning with a quantifier by
a propositional variable and then replacing all remaining atomic formulas by a propositional variable. For example,
$$\bigl((\forall x Px \land Qcz) \rightarrow (Qcz \lor \forall x Px)\bigr)_P =
\bigl((A \land B) \rightarrow (B \lor A)\bigr)$$).*

In the solutions, they produce the following proof:

[image]

I think that (Claim) does not hold and that a mistake is made (for example) in the case that
$\phi$ is of the form $(\neg\alpha)$, as i believe that $\mathfrak{A} \models (\neg\alpha)$ is
not equivalent to $\mathfrak{A} \not\models \alpha$, because of the following definition:
[image]

For example, using (Claim) one could deduce
$$\mathcal{N} \not\models x < y
\; \Leftrightarrow \; \overline{v_\mathcal{N}}((x < y)_P) = F
\; \Leftrightarrow \; \overline{v_\mathcal{N}}((\neg x < y)_P) = T
\; \Leftrightarrow \; \mathcal{N} \models \neg (x < y)
$$
which is not true in general. I suppose instead of using a truth assignment $v_\mathfrak{A}$ in this proof, one should use a truth assignment $v_{\mathfrak{A},s}$ also dependent on an assignment function $s$ into $\mathfrak{A}$.

Am I missing something or is the proof in fact erroneous?

Comment: Yes; see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040634/if-beta-is-an-mathcall-formula-and-beta-p-is-a-tautology-then-beta).